# create view from this query

Tags: mysql, sql, view

The following query

1. Displays result with ranks perfectly but the second query
2. Does not create a view in mysql.

How do I create a view of the query below?  I have tried many ways but unable to figure it out.

1.

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC
```

2.

```
declare @rownum int

CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, name, vote 
FROM uservotes, (SELECT @rownum := 0) t ORDER BY vote DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use user variables in a `VIEW` unfortunately. You'll have to create it the hard way, probably something like:

```
CREATE VIEW V AS 
SELECT COUNT(y.*) as rank, x.name, x.vote
FROM uservotes x 
JOIN uservotes y 
  ON y.votes >= x.votes
GROUP BY x.some_unique_column
ORDER BY x.vote DESC
```

Which will be quite a bit slower then your original query.

Note it will `rank` 2 entries with the same vote the same, if you don't want that, you need a subquery, or an extra `ON` clause to decide tie breaks.

Comment: Sir can you tell me if I can add new column serial_number which just adds the count for each row .Like : serial_number for 1st should be 1 ,2nd 2 then 3 and so on.Basically add serial numbers inruntime.Is it possible if yes then How ? for the same query as above>i really appreciate your time.I am stuck on this issue and cannot resolve it.Thanks.

Comment: No, the `JOIN` on itself is about the only way. You could create a new table though, and update this once in a while if you don't need cutting-edge data? Or go for creating a `PROCEDURE`, that creates that temporary table with an auto-inc column, and adds the data as you like.

Comment: Ah well, I didn't seay _"something like"_ for nothing, was a bit OTOH. [this one works though](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c6c/37)